# No method named `match_command` found for struct `HashMap` in the current scope

Tags: rust

I'm writing a command parser. Here is my code.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

struct Command {
    begin: String,
    command: String,
    args: Vec<String>
}

impl Command {
    fn parse(command: &str) -> Self {
        let command: Vec<&str> = command.split(" ").collect();
        Command {
            begin: command[0][0..1].to_string(),
            command: command[0][1..].to_string(),
            args: command[1..].iter()
                .map(|x| x.to_string())
                .map(|x| x.replace("%s", " "))
                .map(|x| x.replace("%n", "\n"))
                .collect()
        }
    }

    fn prefix(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}{}", self.begin, self.command)
    }
}

impl ToString for Command {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut string = format!("{}{}", self.begin, self.command);
        for i in self.args {
            string.push_str(format!(" {}", i).as_str())
        }
        string
    }
}

trait CommandRegister {
    fn match_command(&self, command: &str) -> Option<fn(args: Vec<String>)>;
}

impl CommandRegister for HashMap<Command, fn(args: Vec<String>)> {
    fn match_command(&self, command: &str) -> Option<fn(args: Vec<String>)> {
        let command = Command::parse(command);
        for i in self {
            if *i.0 == command {
                return Some(*i.1)
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

impl PartialEq<Self> for Command {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.begin == other.begin && self.command == other.command && self.args.len() == other.args.len()
    }
}

impl Eq for Command {
}

impl Hash for Command {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.to_string().hash(state)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let command = Command::parse("/alpha do 1 2");
    println!("Begin: {}", command.begin);
    println!("Command: {}", command.command);
    for i in 0..command.args.len() {
        println!("Arg{i}: {}", command.args[i])
    }
    let mut map: HashMap<&Command, fn(args: Vec<String>)> = HashMap::new();
    let command = Command {
        begin: String::from("/"),
        command: String::from("alpha"),
        args: vec!("arg1".to_string(), "arg2".to_string())
    };
    map.insert(&command, |args: Vec<String>| {
        println!("Arguments length: {}", args.len());
    });
    match map.match_command(command.to_string()) {
        Some(func) => func(command.args)
    }
}
```

The `match_command` gave me an error, it said
`no method named` match_command`found for struct`HashMap `in the current scope`

But I implemented `CommandRegister` trait for HashMap in the scope. I think perhaps it is because of the type convert, but I have no idea how to deal with it. And I also want to ask about the difference between `fn` and `Closure`. If I want to use closure here, is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation isn't found because the types don't match.  Compare:

```
impl CommandRegister for HashMap<Command, fn(args: Vec<String>)> {
```

```
let mut map: HashMap<&Command, fn(args: Vec<String>)> = HashMap::new();
```

One uses `Command` and the other uses `&Command`.

However, note that you are using the `HashMap` *very* inefficiently:

```
for i in self {
    if *i.0 == command {
        return Some(*i.1)
    }
}
```

This performs a linear search over the contents.  The whole point of using a `HashMap` is to look up items by their hash instead of doing a linear search:

```
fn match_command(&self, command: &str) -> Option<fn(args: Vec<String>)> {
    let command = Command::parse(command);
    self.get(&command).copied()
}
```

If this doesn't work, it's because your `Hash` and `PartialEq` implementations compare different things:

```
impl PartialEq<Self> for Command {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.begin == other.begin && self.command == other.command && self.args.len() == other.args.len()
    }
}

impl Hash for Command {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.to_string().hash(state)
    }
}
```

Note that the `PartialEq` implementation only compares the lengths of the vectors.  To agree with your `Hash` implementation, it should compare exactly what `Hash` looks at:

```
impl PartialEq<Self> for Command {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.to_string() == other.to_string()
    }
}
```

The easiest way to handle this would be to remove your own implementations of `Eq`, `PartialEq`, and `Hash`, and instead derive them on your struct:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Command {
```

This will generate implementations for you that look at all struct fields automatically.  The generated `Hash` implementation should perform better than yours, but -- more importantly -- all of the implementations will be *correct.*

Comment: Ok, I will edit like this.

Comment: @EvanLuo If that's the case then your `Hash` should also only consider the length. So your hash implementation should probably be `self.begin.hash(state); self.command.hash(state); self.args.len().hash(state);`.

Comment: Yes, I declared a signature function. It's like {begin}-{command}-{length}, and use self.signature().hash(state).

Comment: But when I used this `self.get(&command).copied()`, it mismatched. If hash map compared by hash?

Comment: @EvanLuo Hashing is used to locate the bucket, then equality is used to find the key within a bucket, so it is absolutely required that `Hash` and `PartialEq` agree about which parts of the structure are relevant to equality. This is so that hash collisions can be correctly handled.